# Every 10 mins: YouTube sound goes down and Windows Media Player stops

Tags: windows-7, audio, youtube, windows-media-player

This is really weird, every 10 minutes, YouTube sound goes down, but not showing it. With this last I mean that the volume controller is max, as is the windows volume controller.
   When this happen I have to rewind or forward the video and the sound goes back to normal, till the next minute of the next tens.

In Windows Media Player, instead of sound going down, it stops (yes, in the exactly same minute).
   Again, not hard solution, I just have to resume the media player.

I checked that this is not a random minute, it's every ten minutes, counting when the computer starts. So, if I switch my computer on at 11.45, the problem will occur at 11.55 the first time.

But it is really annoying stop doing what I am doing (working) to press a button every ten minutes.

I am using Windows 7, 64 bits. Any help is apreciated.

**Edit:**

Starting Windows in Clean Boot Mode solves the issue.

Comment: If you boot Windows in [Clean Boot mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135), does that help?

Comment: Yeap, totally helped, is there any way of solving the issue without starting in Clean Boot mode? Is there any restriction botting like that?

Comment: Clean Boot definitely isn't a solution, it's just a troubleshooting aid. See `How to determine what is causing the problem by performing a clean boot` in the linked article to selectively disable services and startup items and narrow it down to a single culprit. Then please report back the culprit service or startup item here.

Comment: Well, it wasn't any service causing trouble. It was a startup item, the Google Chrome, here is a screen: http://prntscr.com/9vxcsp
Full info: **(Startup element | Manufacturer | Command | Location)**  _(Google Chrome | Google Inc. | "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-startup-window | HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run)_

Comment: Weird that Google Chrome is causing this. Simply disabling the startup item might be enough to fix the issue. If not, uninstall or update Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, did that and up to now it's working well. Thank you so much for the help